# unable to retrive list inside list in JSTL

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am unable to retrieve list data from JSTL
here is my bean

```
public class ProjectData {
    public List <String> srNumbers;
    public String comments;

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
        }
    public List<String> getSrNumbers() {
        return srNumbers;
        }
    }
```

This is my html snipet

```
<c:forEach items="${projectDataList}" var="projectDataList">
    <c:forEach items="${projectDataList.srNumbers}" var="srNumbers">
        <c:out value="${srNumbers}" />, 
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

below is what I am setting in the servlet

```
request.setAttribute("projectDataList", projectDataList);
```

the expected output is given below

```
    sr1,sr2,sr3
```

Defined the setters already

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for the list in `ProjectData`?

Comment: and what is actual output /error ? @Rohit just getters are enough

Comment: Why there is a `comma` in after the `c:out` tag?

Comment: @Octopus: It must be for the output as `sr1,sr2,sr3`

Comment: Give more code of ProjectData class.

Comment: How did you bind `projectDataList`?

Comment: @Ravinder Thanks man,  got it. Thought `<c:out value="${srNumbers}," />`  is only option

Comment: @Ravinder String []SRNumbers={"SR121212","SR212131"}; 
  List<ProjectData> projectDataList = new ArrayList<ProjectData>();
  projectDataList.add(new ProjectData(Arrays.asList(SRNumbers),  "my"));

Comment: could you share what exception you are  getting and uri of your taglib

Comment: no exception just the blank output  &   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<c:forEach items="${projectDataList}" var="projectDataList">
    ${fn:join(projectDataList.srNumbers.toArray(), ',')}
</c:forEach>
```

Which avoids a "hanging" comma, which your current code would produce. Not sure about the `.toArray()` part as I haven't tested the code but an alternative could be to simply add another method to your `ProjectData` class like:

```
import  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class ProjectData {
    public List <String> srNumbers;
    public String comments;

    public String getSrNumbersJoined() {
        return StringUtils.join(srNumbers, ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: First part didn't work for me but the later did. Thanks